# Application defined or object defined error in function

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting the Run-Time error 1004 application-defined or object defined error which I updated the function below to include the "access" code. I cant seem to find where my issue is.

```
Dim Access As Worksheet
Dim report As Worksheet
Dim complete As Worksheet

Sub finalOverlay()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Access = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Access")
    Set report = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
    Set complete = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Implementation Complete")

    Dim i As Long

    For x = 2 To Access.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For i = 2 To report.UsedRange.Rows.Count


            getRemainingControls (i)

            ' update completed list if no more actions outstanding
            If report.Cells(i, 17) = 0 Then                    
                 t = setComplete(report.Cells(i, 1), i)
            End If

            S = getComplete(report.Cells(i, 1), i)

            ' Add BAU Ageing
            report.Cells(i, 22) = BAUAgeing(i)

            ' Disposition Date past
            If report.Cells(i, 34) <> "" Then
                If CDate(report.Cells(i, 34)) < Date Then
                    report.Cells(i, 34).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            End If


            ' Proposed Status for too long
            If report.Cells(i, 4) = "Proposed" Then
                report.Cells(i, 18) = CInt(Date - CDate(report.Cells(i, 38)))
                If report.Cells(i, 18) > 30 Then
                    report.Cells(i, 18).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
               End If
            End If


        Next i
    Next x

    For n = 2 To report.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If report.Cells(n, 19) <> " " And _
           report.Cells(n, 19) > 305 And _
           report.Cells(n, 23) = "Yes" And _
           report.Cells(n, 3) <> "LOW" And _
           report.Cells(n, 39) <> "NO" Then
              report.Cells(n, 19).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
        End If

        If report.Cells(n, 19) <> " " And _
           report.Cells(n, 19) > 60 And _
           report.Cells(n, 24) <> "Complete" And _
           report.Cells(n, 24) <> "" And _
           report.Cells(n, 23) = "Yes" And _
           report.Cells(n, 3) <> "LOW" And _
           report.Cells(n, 39) <> "NO" Then
               report.Cells(n, 19).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If

        If report.Cells(n, 20) > 305 And _
           report.Cells(n, 20) < 364 And _
           report.Cells(n, 29) = "Complete" And _
           report.Cells(n, 23) = "Yes" And _
           report.Cells(n, 3) <> "LOW" And _
           report.Cells(n, 39) <> "NO" Then
               report.Cells(n, 20).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
        End If

        If report.Cells(n, 20) > 60 And _
           report.Cells(n, 29) <> "Complete" And _
           report.Cells(n, 23) = "Yes" And _
           report.Cells(n, 3) <> "LOW" And _
           report.Cells(n, 39) <> "NO" Then
               report.Cells(n, 20).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If

    Next n

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function BAUAgeing(i As Long)

    If report.Cells(i, 17) > 0 And _
       report.Cells(i, 6) <> "" And _
       report.Cells(i, 23) = "No" Then
           BAUAgeing = Date - CDate(report.Cells(i, 6))

    Else
    End If

    If report.Cells(i, 4) = "Newly Disclosed" And Access.Cells(x, 35) = "" Then
        BAUAgeing = Date - CDate(report.Cells(i, 38))
    Else
        BAUAgeing = Date - CDate(Mid(Access.Cells(x, 35), 16, 10))
    End If

    If report.Cells(i, 4) = "Proposed" And Access.Cells(x, 35) = "" Then
        BAUAgeing = Date - CDate(report.Cells(i, 38))
    Else
        BAUAgeing = Date - CDate(Mid(Access.Cells(x, 35), 16, 10))
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: You can't nest a function in a sub (if that's what you're doing).

Comment: This worked fine without the &quot;access&quot; code. In the sub is called using

    Report.cells(i,22) = BAUAging(i)

Comment: Which line of your code is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your function to take `x` as an argument, otherwise it will have no value and you'll get `1004` error:

```
Function BAUAgeing(i As Long, x as long)
```

And in your code above, also change the argument:

```
' Add BAU Ageing
report.Cells(i, 22) = BAUAgeing(i, x)
```

Additionally, you really should add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module and declare **all** of your variables. You declare `i`,  but not `t`, `x`, `S`... leaves a lot of room for mistakes.